# Images in post when viewed using Chrome on Android are sometimes misplaced

Tags: bug, design, images, android, mobile-chrome

Images in post when viewed using Chrome on Android are sometimes misplaced.

Example from [Why are there so many subway station signs between Yau Ma Tei station and Mong Kok station on Google Maps?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148631/1810): the image

> [image]

has different location depending on whether it is viewed on Chrome on computer or Chrome on Android.

As viewed in Chrome on computer:

> [image]

As viewed in Chrome on Android,

> [image: enter image description]

is placed on a new line:

> [image]

Comment: Getting downvoted for reporting a bug, that's how I know I am on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is it not supposed to be like that? It’s the same in the iOS app.

Comment: @Laurel that'd probably be better to ensure consistent rendering across devices. What would be the point to go to a new line in the given example?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile version of the website [includes this CSS](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/travel/mobile.css):

```css
.post-text img {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block
}
```

Developers probably decided that images tend to be be big (and are rarely used inline), so centered images would be appropriate on mobile devices with small screens and would look better this way. I suspect it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).